# RhythmBox only plays downloaded music when the Archive Manager is open

Tags: 12.04, rhythmbox, notify-osd, archive, zip

Ubuntu 12.04.

I have downloaded some music (They're in a ZIP format, by the way), and they play fine, and the NotifyOSD comes up, as usual. But when I play the music, the Archive Manager **HAS** to stay open, because when I quit the Manager, the music just stops, and the music disappears from RhythmBox altogether.

How do I stop this? Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well when the archive manager is opened the audio becomes sort of "temporaily unzipped", so you can look and play the files. When the archive manager isn't open, it is in a zipped form, and Rhythmbox can't play compressed files.

Solution: Type `unzip (filename.zip)` in terminal. Or in archive manager press Extract, select where you want the files to go, and press "extract" or whatever confirm button.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to solve this in a graphical interference? I'm not so used to terminal.